# docker is displaying error regarding absolute path while installing label-studio

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rpa

I am working on NER ML model which requires label-studio to be get installed on the pc. I am using this  command

```
`docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`/mydata:/label-studio/data heartexlabs/label-studio:latest`
```

for installation of label-studio in terminal but getting the below error.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: create `pwd`/mydata: "`pwd`/mydata" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
```

The docker is running on windows 10.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: `The docker is running on windows 10.` <= the command you are using contains unix shell expression that will not work in a windows cmd/powershell (i.e. backtik enclosed `pwd` command to get the current working directory).

Comment: so how to run it on windows shell.. As my docker is installed and is running on windows.

Comment: You replace the path to your bind mount with an absolute path on the filesystem (docker requires that). There might be a way to get the current directory inside a command in windows but I have no idea. Note as well that the path separator for the local (i.e. on disk) directory should be a backslash

Answer (score 0):

`pwd` can't be used on Windows, it's linux-only. Replace it with absolute paths please, e.g.:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -v c:/projects/mydata:/label-studio/data heartexlabs/label-studio:latest
```